# Linq order IEnumerable (by the enumerated elements themselves)

Tags: .net, linq, sorting

This might seem like an obvious question, and probably there will be previous questions about this topic, please point out and close if necesary because I can't find them.

Is there any Linq extension method that returns an ordered sequence by the elements themselves? I know it can be achieved by:

```
IEnumerable<int> myIntegers = new int[]{4, 6, 34, 987, -13};
IEnumerable<int> myOrderedIntegers = myIntegers.OrderBy(i => i);
```

I don't like this, it seems too verbose for such a simple operation. I know I could also do:

```
List<int> myOtherOrderedIntegers = myIntegers.ToList();
myOtherOrderedIntegers.Sort();
```

But uugh... bye bye deferred evaluation, and even more verbose. I could write my extension methods like...

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Order<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements) => elements.OrderBy(e => e);
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderDescending<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements) => elements.OrderByDescending(e => e);
```

Is there already any Linq extension method that can achieve this simple operation? I find it extrange that it isn't implemented already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there's not. Is `OrderBy(i => i)` really that verbose to you?

Comment: Why do you find `IEnumerable<int> myOrderedIntegers = myIntegers.OrderBy(i => i);` too verbose?

Comment: You extension methods will not work correctly for ordering lists with complex types(unless your type implements `IComparable<T>`)

Comment: Well, it is not like it is really a problem, I just thought it could be more clear if such a method existed (the lambda in this context seems unnecesary to me). Thank you for your answers, feel free to properly answer and i'll upvote and select.

Comment: @DanielGarcíaRubio The lambda makes sense if you consider the extension methods are primarily there to support the query syntax, where you need to specify the thing you are ordering by even if it's a single column (ie, self). Something like `Order()` makes less sense because query syntax would never have a use for it. People have created lots of additional extensions, a popular one being MoreLINQ.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth fair enough, I didn't think of the query syntax. I guess they could just have done a method like this unavailable by query syntax, but they didn't see the necessity in the first place, as it isn't really an issue.

Comment: @DanielGarcíaRubio Yeah pretty much. Value-add for it would be low from the perspective of the framework, also considering how easy it is to plug the gap yourself with a simple wrapper method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any other, less verbose method than `myIntegers.OrderBy(i => i)`? Like `myIntegers.Order()`? No there is not. You can write them yourself if you want to, you already pasted the code. You will have to live with the 8 bytes of wasted space in your source.

Comment: Well apparently this is a method Sort(), Asker just typed it. He only has to put it in some common library.